# Kibana 4 , making pie chart , error message

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I was trying to create a pie chart in Kibana 4 dashboard. And I was trying for a split slice one. But when I select the field type,I get the following error: "Pie chart response converter:Splitting charts without splitting sliced is not supported.Pretend that we are just splitting slices".
Why is this error?.

This is the screenshot of the above error. I have marked it with a yellow rectangle and numbered it as 1. !https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDSfg.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do a "split slice " operation on a pie chart,first you need to create a pie chart with slices.Here from what I understand,you tried to give the option "split chart" first,which actually is to make differrent pie charts,in the same row or column,which needs more than one pie-chart. This also requires pie-charts (with slices) to be created first. So you need to create pie-charts and then only you can use "split chart". i
In the figures below,the first one shows an ordinary pie-chart created by "split-slice" and the second one shows five pie charts stacked horizontally using the "split chart" method.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think this is because you chose "Split Chart" and what you want to do is "Split Slice". So, just choose "Splice Slice" and everything should work fine.

Comment: K..seems the problem is now solved. But is "split slice" an option for dividing the slices again?.

Comment: Yes, you can divide slices again and again, for [example](http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcROXoggqYY_ExYXP_zNw9R-T4jWOEofE-u9jaCjDFpOFwE3LS97H4mWW3vcFA).
Split slice is for dividing your slice again and again, while spliting chart is to produce different pie charts based on different Terms for [example](http://www.elasticsearch.org/content/uploads/2014/10/Screen-Shot-2014-10-01-at-12.49.50-PM.png). Hope it will be clear.